# Best way to Enable Android Support Library Debugging Flag

Tags: android, debugging, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I'm running into many problems with the Android Support Library's ViewPager widget.  Due to lack of documentation and just incorrect behavior, I've been learning how things work based on the source.

Looking at the source, I see that the ViewPager, I see a [constant](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#86) defined as

```
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
```

If I can set this to `true`, then I can enable all the debugging for the ViewPager class

However, I can't determine how to modify this value at runtime.  Reflection didn't seem to have access to it.

Is the only way to change this flag is by recompiling the source?

Comment: `ViewPager` only relies on the Support Library. You could copy/paste it, then change the flag.

Comment: Great idea adneal.  I may end up doing this for the path of least resistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.remove the "final" property; 
2.add a method allowed to modify the DEBUG value;
3.recompile the source.

Answer (score 0):

For enabling debug, maybe you should extends this class firstly. Then use your customized class instead of ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm trying to access the debugging messages of the private methods of ViewPager.  So unfortunately, this approach won't work (unless I'm missing something, which is known to happen!)

Answer (score 0):

A `final` variable cannot be changed after it is assigned therefore you would need to recompile from source with `DEBUG = true` if you want to enable the built in debugging statements.